# Bash: Is there a way to see which files in a directory are of a certain file extension?

Tags: bash

I am trying to (recursively) check one of my directories to see which files are XML files. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -name "*.xml"
```

Finds all files in the given directory (and all subdirectories) with a name ending with `.xml`. Use `-iname` for case insensitive name matching instead.

Comment: To do this recursively?

Comment: @DarkTemplar It already is.

Comment: @DarkTemplar You're welcome. Btw, `find` is much more powerful and really handy with many different problems. Check out its `man` page.

Comment: Aight. Got it ;)